# Populating an array with a loop pulling from JSON

Tags: arrays, for-loop, getjson, populate

I want to populate an array of objects with data pulled from a getJSON function.

I'm currently doing it object by object, but know it'd be much cleaner with a for loop...

Here's the getJSON:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json?jsonp=?",
    function(data) {

        var imageurl1 = data.data.children[0].data.url;
        var imagecaption1 = data.data.children[0].data.title;;
        var commentlink1 = "http://www.reddit.com" + data.data.children[0].data.permalink;

        var imageurl2 = data.data.children[1].data.url;
        var imagecaption2 = data.data.children[1].data.title;
        var commentlink2 = "http://www.reddit.com" + data.data.children[1].data.permalink;

       }
```

And here's the array I'm using the data for

```
var lightboximages = [
 { 
    src: imageurl1,
    caption: imagecaption1,
    comments: commentlink1
 }, { 
    src: imageurl2,
    caption: imagecaption2,
    comments: commentlink2
 }]
```

Any help with the loop would be much appreciated!

Comment: (there are 10 objects in the array, but put two here for brevity)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this is the idea:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json?jsonp=?",
    function(data) {
       var lightboxArray = [];
       for (var i=0; i<data.data.children.length; i++) {
           var child = data.data.children[i];
           var lightboxObj = {"src":child.data.url, "caption":child.data.title, "comments":child.data.permalink};
           lightboxArray.push(lightboxObj);
       }
       // now call some function to process the array we've built
    });
```

Comment: Bingo... huge thanks. As an addendum, to ensure only 10 pics pulled i added a slice -  data.data.children.slice(0, 9).length

Comment: I think slice excludes the last item so you may want to do slice(0,10).  But for a safer approach, to ensure that you don't have problems with a returned array that has fewer than 10 items anyway, I'd simply change the test in the for loop to read "i<Math.min(10, data.data.children.length)".

Comment: sorry, didn't realise had to mark as answered, have now. Thanks again.